# AlarmManager and the PendingIntent that failed

Tags: android, android-emulator

In order to learn how to use the AlarmManager I created an activity
that consists of a single button. When the button is pressed the
activity creates an Intent of itself and loads it into the
AlarmManager 3 seconds in the future before finishing.

So activity opens, user pushes button, activity closes, 3 seconds
later activity opens, repeat.

Problem is instead of opening an activity 3 seconds later I get an
error:
"The application [myappname] has stopped unexpectedly. Please try
again." Except when I call a Toast instead, that worked.

Here's the code for the button:

```
thanksButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
               setResult(RESULT_OK);
               Intent intent = new Intent(myappname.this,
myappnameBroadcastReceiver.class);
               PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
(myappname.this, 0, intent, 0);
               Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
               calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
               AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService
(ALARM_SERVICE);
               am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
appIntent);

               finish();
               }

       });
```

Here's the broadcast receiver:

```
package com.myappname;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class myappnameBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                       context.startActivity(new Intent(context, myappname.class));
       }
}
```

and here's the lines from the manifest.xml

```
       <receiver
               android:name=".myappnameBroadcastReceiver"
               android:process=":remote">
       </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So activity opens, user pushes button, activity closes, 3 seconds later activity opens, repeat.

You do not need any service if you just want to start your activity when the alarm goes off. Create a PendingIntent that starts your activity, that's all. Try this in your activity class - `MyActivity` in my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent appIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```